# what's the difference between `my ($h, @s) = @_;` and `my ($h, @s) = grep $_, @_;`

Tags: perl, grep

I read this code in a book named 'High-order Perl`, I just don't understand why the bother to use grep, but if I changed to the first statement, things start go wrong, can anyone please explain it a bit? thanks.

Context: The code located in the chapter 6 and section 5, in the

```
sub union {
my ($h, @s) = grep $_, @_;
  return unless $h;
  return $h unless @s;
  node(head($h), promise {
  union(@s, tail($h));
 });
}
```

Comment: What values are in the list? What section of the book are you talking about? This would be easier to answer with context.

Comment: [The book](http://hop.perl.plover.com/) is called _Higher Order Perl_, by Mark Jason Dominus. Can you please point to the page or chapter? This is a bit out of context. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`my ($h, @s) = @_;` takes the first value of the array `@_` and put it in `$h` and the rest in `@s`.

`my ($h, @s) = grep $_, @_;` takes the first true value and puts it in `$h` and the rest of the true values and puts it in `@s`.

True values in perl are things that are not the empty string '', 0 or undef.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the difference between the two statements is the use of the `grep` function then I'd suggest that a good place to get an answer to your question is to read [the documentation for `grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

> grep BLOCK LIST
>
> grep EXPR,LIST
>
> This is similar in spirit to, but not the same as, grep(1) and its
>   relatives. In particular, it is not limited to using regular
>   expressions.
>
> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting
>   `$_` to each element) and returns the list value consisting of those
>   elements for which the expression evaluated to true. In scalar
>   context, returns the number of times the expression was true.